# Using c++ dll as an assembly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, dll, c++-cli

I know I can register a .NET dll as an assembly and call a function within my sql query. But I'm getting confusing statements as to using a c++ or c++/cli dll for the same purpose.

The link below describes a way to just do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hc912f03(v=vs.120).aspx

but then I'm getting the following error message:

CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'libname' failed because assembly 'libname' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.

Another document actually states that only pure .NET modules can be used.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2013/02/23/unable-to-register-net-framework-assembly-not-in-the-supported-list.aspx

So I'm wondering what is true and if possible how to use a c++ dll with SQL Server 2012?

I have tried to wrap my c++ dll with a c++/cli wrapper compiled with /clr:safe but to no success.

Comment: Are you referring to [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963(v=vs.110).aspx)? What exact purpose are you trying to achieve by adding `.dll` to SQL Server?

Comment: Adding a .dll gives me the opportunity to call a function inside a sql statement. For instance some advanced math function that's not provided by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This article has some workarounds about creating the dll. After creating c++ dll, a C# dll is created to wrap the c++ dll:

https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/calling-c-from-sql-clr-c-code/